# WalletConnectProvider from react-native-dapp not working

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement a functionality in my react-native app where in I can connect my app with metamask or any other non-custodial wallet app. The library I am using for this is https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/react-native-dapp.

The following is the code snippet:

```
<WalletConnectProvider
  redirectUrl={Platform.OS === 'web' ? window.location.origin : 'yourappscheme://'}
  storageOptions= {{
    asyncStorage AsyncStorage,
  }}>
  <>{/* awesome app here */}</>
</WalletConnectProvider>
```

However, when I try to run the app, it shows the following errors:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[0], "./providers").WalletConnectProvider')

Error: Requiring module "node_modules\@walletconnect\react-native-dapp\dist\providers\index.js", which threw an exception: TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null.
```

Any idea why this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issues due to the use of npx rn-nodeify --install --hack.

Tried using "node-libs-react-native" inside the devDependencies as suggested at
https://github.com/WalletConnect/walletconnect-monorepo/issues/753

Comment: If you found your own solution please mark your answer as correct